# Cordova iOS: Install new simulator images

Tags: ios, cordova

I want to emulate my app on an iPad but when I run look for images, I seem to have none:

```
$ cordova run ios --list
Available ios devices:
Available ios virtual devices:
```

How can I install them?  When I look at xcode, I have many available but not from the command line.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `run` command is for physical attached devices and running emulators. Use the [`emulate`](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/8.x/reference/cordova-cli/index.html#cordova-emulate-command) command for virtual devices.

```
cordova emulate --list
```

This shows a list of available virtual devices.

Comment: Just tried and my list of available iOS simulators is empty

Comment: This `cordova run ios --list --emulator` command should also work. I've used cordova only inside of ionic projects. Cordova version I used is 8.0.0. Maybe you could build the project and open the generated Xcode project to check if the project and emulator are ok.